# How to display the all the employee names who work under one department using JOIN?

Tags: mysql, workbench

I am working on a MySQL on workbench.

I wanted to display all the employee names that are working on the same department(e.g. Finance department) using JOIN.

I've created two tables.

1st table is named Employees with attributes EmployeeID, EmployeeName, and DepartmentID.

```
EmployeeID = 3012, 3013, 3014
EmployeeName =John, Lisa, Manny
DepartmentID = 1005, 1006, 1005
```

2nd table is named department with attributes DepartmentID and DepartmentName.

```
DepartmentID = 1005, 1006
DepartmentName = Finace, Human Resources
```

I wanted to display the employee names and the department (but only in the Finance department).

Below is my attempt:

```
SELECT employees.emp_name, employees.job_name, employees.salary, department.dep_name
FROM employees
INNER JOIN department WHERE employees.dep_id=department.dep_id
```

But as you see, the code above, displays both the Finance and Human Department.

How can i only display those in the Finace department?

Comment: ...`and department.name = 'Finace'`?

Comment: I would prefer to use an ON clause in the join rather than generating a cartesian product and filtering with a where condition , and have a where condition which filters on department.